# Updating Visualforce Email Template

Tags: visualforce, email-template

I have a custom Visualforce Email Template that is working as expected when sent via an email alert on the workflow rule. I am now trying to update that Visualforce Email Template with some additional text (just text, no formatting or merge fields). However, making the updates and after saving the template, the HTML Preview of the template is not updated with the new text, nor is the email itself when sent out. (The Plain Text Preview is updated though). Has anyone seen similar issues or know what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at your template, there are a few tags to pay attention to. Notice that there are separate tags for `<messaging:htmlEmailBody>` and `<messaging:plainTextEmailBody>`. Making changes inside one tag will not affect the other. If you have both tags defined, you must add your copy to both.

```
<messaging:emailTemplate>
    <messaging:htmlEmailBody>
        <!-- html content -->
    </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
    <messaging:plainTextEmailBody>
        <!-- plain text content -->
    </messaging:plainTextEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Comment: That was exactly it, I was only making my updates within the <messaging:plainTextEmailBody> tags.